# How to write a trigger that blocks the entire calendar?

Tags: trigger

Problem: If we selects the "All Day Event" checkbox on the event, vs physically blocking out a specified time (ex. 7 to 4), the system doesn’t stop overlapping appointments.

Can any one help me how to create a trigger that blocks the entire calendar if the "All Day Event" checkbox is selected.?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! We can help you troubleshoot or improve a trigger but request that you start it yourself and show what you've tried first. See http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for more details.

Comment: Here's something to help get you started with your coding. I strongly suspect the problem you're having is closely related to your company's work hours. I look forward to seeing the code you come up with. :)